# Working with omega sub-theme and having trouble to make susy, sass and compass work properly

Tags: ruby, drupal, compass-sass, susy-compass

I'm working with omega sub-theme and i'm having trouble to make susy, sass and compass work properly.

Every single time i go to terminal and execute `$ compass watch` i get the next result:

> LoadError on line 51 of /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb: no such file to load -- rgbapng
>   Run with --trace to see the full backtrace

I have trie diferent version of Ruby using RVM and still have the same problem.

The next is the result of the `--trace` command:

> /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in `require'
>     /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/configuration/data.rb:161:in`require'
>     /Users/----/----/----/sites/all/themes/----/config.rb:21:in `get_binding'
>     /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/configuration/serialization.rb:20:in`get_binding'
>     /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/configuration/serialization.rb:23:in `parse_string'
>     /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/configuration/serialization.rb:15:in`_parse'
>     /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/configuration/serialization.rb:14:in `open'
>     /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/configuration/serialization.rb:14:in`_parse'
>     /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/configuration/file_data.rb:7:in `new_from_file'
>     /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/configuration/inheritance.rb:204:in`with_defaults'
>     /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/configuration/file_data.rb:6:in `new_from_file'
>     /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/configuration/helpers.rb:42:in`configuration_for'
>     /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/configuration/helpers.rb:97:in `add_project_configuration'
>     /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/commands/project_base.rb:31:in`add_project_configuration'
>     /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/commands/project_base.rb:25:in `configure!'
>     /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/commands/project_base.rb:15:in`initialize'
>     /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/commands/update_project.rb:37:in `initialize'
>     /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/exec/sub_command_ui.rb:42:in`new'
>     /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/exec/sub_command_ui.rb:42:in `perform!'
>     /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/exec/sub_command_ui.rb:15:in`run!'
>     /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:30
>     /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:44:in `call'
>     /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:44
>     /usr/bin/compass:23:in`load'
>     /usr/bin/compass:23

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Have you tried installing the rgbapng gem?

Comment: Yes @EricMeyer, the problem is that i was using **gem install rgbang** and it is **gem install compass-rgbang** that one should be using. Thanks for commenting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was simple, i was using the wrong command to install the rgbapng gem, instead of using `gem install rgbang` you should be using `gem install compass-rgbang`.